# What is a reasonable gas limit for a transaction to invest in an ICO?

Tags: gas

IndaHash asks for a gas limit of 250 000.
Since it's $675 per ether, a gas is 675/100k, 
the transaction could cost 250000*$675/100k = $1687.

Is my math wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your math is wrong.

It has 250.000 of gas limit. And when you send the transaction, you can choose your gas price in GWEI. It can be 1, 2, 100 , etc GWEI. If you check https://ethgasstation.info/ you will see that your transaction would cost at this moment, setting gas price at 20GWEI, $3,38 and not $1687.